# Renaming column of one dataframe by extracting from combination of series and dataframe column names

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rename, multiple-columns

In the line below, I am renaming the columns of pnlsummary dataframe from the column names of three series (totalheldmw, totalcost and totalsellprofit) and one dataframe (totalheldprofit).

The difficulty I have is to iterate over the column names of the dataframe. I have manually assigned the names as you can see below. I would suppose there is an efficient way of iterating over the column names of the dataframe. Please advice.

```
pnlsummary.columns =
[totalheldmw.name[0],totalcost.name[0],totalsellprofit.name[0],
totalheldprofit.columns[0],totalheldprofit.columns[1],
totalheldprofit.columns[2],totalheldprofit.columns[3]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need create `list` by constants and then add columns names converted to `list`:

```
pnlsummary.columns = [totalheldmw.name[0],totalcost.name[0],totalsellprofit.name[0]] +
                      totalheldprofit.columns[0:3].astype(str).tolist()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

df.columns = ['a','s','d'] + df.columns[0:3].tolist()
print (df)
   a  s  d  A  B  C
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Comment: The issue I am running into is that the dataframe has timestamps but the prior series is string. So, I would have to convert the list to str and then add. What would be the best way?

Comment: I think the simpliest is `totalheldprofit.columns[0:3].astype(str).tolist()`

Comment: pnlsummary.columns=[totalheldmw.name[0],totalcost.name[0],totalsellprofit.name[0] + totalheldprofit.columns[0:3].astype(str).tolist()]

TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly. Thoughts?

Comment: You have wrong `[]`, need `pnlsummary.columns=[totalheldmw.name[0],totalcost.name[0],to‌​talsellprofit.name[0‌​] ] + totalheldprofit.columns[0:3].astype(str).tolist() `